# Algorithm for checking if point is part of a line not working well when the line is going downwards

Tags: algorithm, go, geometry

The code is written in GoLang but I'd like to think that this is more like language agnostic, even though GoLang specific suggestions are welcome. I have a struct `Point`

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}
```

and I'm having an array of `Points []Point` and I want to draw a lines starting from **Points[0] -> Points[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s55de.png)... Points[n]**

The canvas is a rectangle so maybe this is not the best solution but I've decided to iterate each pixel from the canvas and check if the current pixel is part of any line and give another color:

```
m := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 400, 400))

for i := 0; i <= 400; i++ {
    for j := 0; j <= 400; j++ {
        m.Set(i, j, p.At(i, j))
    }
}
```

so the `At` method should return a color if the pixel is part of a line and this part gives me some troubles. Currently I have this:

```
tempPoint := Point{X: x, Y: y}
for i := 1; i < len(p.Points); i++ {
    if p.Points[i].X == tempPoint.X && p.Points[i].Y == tempPoint.Y {
        return color.Alpha{255}
    }

    if is_between(p.Points[i-1], tempPoint, p.Points[i]) {
        return color.Alpha{255}
    }
}
return color.Alpha{0}
```

and finally the `is_between` function which should return true or false:

```
func is_between(a, c, b Point) bool {
  c1 := (b.X-a.X)*(c.Y-a.Y) == (c.X-a.X)*(b.Y-a.Y)
  c2 := math.Abs(compare(a.X, c.X)+compare(b.X, c.X)) <= 1
  c3 := math.Abs(compare(a.Y, c.Y)+compare(b.Y, c.Y)) <= 1

  return c1 && c2 && c3
}
```

this is the `compare` function:

```
func compare(x, y int) float64 {
  if x > y {
    return 1
  } else if x == y {
    return 0
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}
```

So having this code if I enter some points:

```
Point{X: 5, Y: 180}
Point{X: 50, Y: 200}
Point{X: 100, Y: 150}
Point{X: 200, Y: 150}
Point{X: 250, Y: 190}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see the horizontal and the upwards lines are OK, but the lines that go downwards have just several pixels painted. I suspect it's the `is_between` function. The main goal isn't this algorithm but I would like to get some acceptable picture anyways.

I'm pretty sure it's the `is_between` function which maybe is too precise or I don't know, but I would appreciate any help in order to fix this.

Comment: It seems to be doing what you *say* you want, but you see gaps because it only shows the grid points that are *exactly* on the line, and usually the line goes *between* grid points.  I can't really suggest a fix, because I don't know what you really want.  This doesn't seem like a reasonable way to draw lines at all.

Comment: @MattTimmermans What I want is pretty standard I have a collection of points and I want, speaking more generally, to draw a path from the first to the last point (assuming only correct inputs for now). In order to do that I am trying to implement the `image` interface from GoLang. What would you consider a better approach to draw lines?

Comment: I think @MattTimmermans is right; the line going up happens to have a gradient of exactly 1, so there are no gaps because the gradient is an integer. It's probably a coincidence that the two lines with gradients which are not integers are the two which are going downwards.

Comment: Paint the whole image black, and then draw each line with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks, I will take a look. Is it not possible to add some sort of tolerance or something that would make my current implementations works without gaps?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't look quite right and checking each pixel for intersection with every line is very inefficient

Comment: @MattTimmermans I agree. I already changed the drawing algorithm with the one provided by you, however I am wondering, since the `image` interface provides an `At` method which returns a `color` isn't the idea exactly to check each individual pixel and determine it's color based on certain conditions? Generally the question is not about GoLang specifically but I would really appreciate if you could shed some light regarding where my logic is going wrong.

Comment: It's not appropriate for `p` to implement the image interface.  That's for raster images like `m`, in which case `At` is a simple memory lookup

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you for the tips. One last question, by any chance can you link me to a resource where the `image` interface is used correctly? Even though it's ugly I though I was getting it right when I left the job about what color each pixel should be, to the `At` func. Now that you say that thus func is a simple memory lookup I am really interested to see correctly implemented along with the rest of the interface. Regardless, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a go programmer.  Developers wouldn't typically make their own implementations of this interface, though.  You could presumably look at the implementations that go comes with.